# Moving a ball through a Cylinder

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation

I'm moving a ball through a hollow cylinder (sub divided) and I want the cylinder to bulge as the ball travels and return to form afterwards.  I did this by making the cylinder a cloth object and the ball a collision object.  I'm getting some weird results, but I don't even think this is required.  Is there a way I can do this without creating the cloth?  A modifier perhaps?  I'm looking into forcefield physics, but it's probably an overkill.

Let me know if screen shots are required...  I didn't post any because it's really simple. Just 2 basic shapes.

Comment: A cast modifier on the cylinder does this well.  (Not on my Blender machine, so going on memory
for button/slot names)

Place an empty some distance from one of the cylinder's ends with the cast modifier nominating the empty as the object. Move the empty towards the cylinder.  If the empty is traveling through the cylinder's exact center axis, it will bulge the cylinder evenly at that immediate area only.  Make sure to have plenty of subdivisions along the cylinder's length.  An example Blend file is available if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, what are the settings for the cast mod?  I saw some videos of it, it deforms shapes weirdly. I can't seem predict what my input will yield.

Comment: the Cast modifier is rather easy to use, you need to create an empty that will be your Control Object, and play with the Factor and Radius

Comment: So, did you get this going?  @Jimmy Lin ?